# R: Waldtest: "Error in solve.default(vc[ovar, ovar]) : 'a' is 0-diml"

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

If there is already an answer to my problem, i apologize for asking my question. So far, I couldn't find one.

I'm currently doing a regression for financial data of bonds. Objective of my regression is to determine if two portfolios of bonds are showing significant different yields. 
I´m controlling for 4 variables (V1 to V4) to control for other sources of risk.

The regression formula is the following:

(one regression for "High-Portfolio", one regression for "Low-Portfolio")

```
ield(p)=∝(p)+ 1(p)*V1+2(p)*V2+3(p)*V3(p)+4(p)*V4(p)
```

which results in the following code in R:

```
   Regression_High <- lm(T_Portfolio ~ T_Slope +T_Credit+T_Ratingscore+ T_Duration)


 (construct variables for Low-Portfolio)


   Regression_Low <- lm(T_Portfolio ~ T_Slope +T_Credit+T_Ratingscore+ T_Duration)
```

The idea now is to compare the two intercepts to determine if the two portfolios show different yields.

For that reason, i want to use a Wald test to determine the joint significance of the intercepts: The test statistic is asymptotically x²-distributed
with 2 degrees of freedom.

```
library(aod)
library(lmtest)
Vcov=vcov(Regression_High,Regression_Low)

1. waldtest(Regression_High, Regression_Low, vcov=Vcov,test="Chisq",name=NULL)

2. waldtest(Regression_High, Regression_Low, test="Chisq")
```

Both of my attempts produce the following error message:

```
Error in solve.default(vc[ovar, ovar]) : 'a' is 0-diml
```

Does anybody know how to conduct the waldtest correctly or where my mistake is?

Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Simon

Reproducible example:

```
#loading packages
library(plm)
library(aod)
library(lmtest)

#Data "High-Portfolio"
y=rnorm(10)
v1=rnorm(10)
v2=rnorm(10)
v3=rnorm(10)
v4=rnorm(10)

#Regression 1

lm1<-lm(y~v1+v2+v3+v4)

#Data "Low-Portfolio"
y=rnorm(10)
v1=rnorm(10)
v2=rnorm(10)
v3=rnorm(10)
v4=rnorm(10)

#Regression 2 

lm2<-lm(y~v1+v2+v3+v4)

#Waldtest
library(aod)
library(lmtest)
Vcov=vcov(lm1,lm2)

#Attempt 1
waldtest(lm1,lm2, vcov=Vcov,test="Chisq",name=NULL)

#Attempt 2
waldtest(lm1, lm2, test="Chisq")
```

Comment: done. Thank you !

Comment: Perhaps run one model with a an additional categorical variable with `high` and `low` levels, which will interact with all `x`  and compare it to a model without the interactions..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will try it. But im not sure if I fully understand what you suggest since my statistical knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the waldtest takes two different models on the same object (not two models on two different objects). You need different variables in your two models in order for it to run.
The error is thrown at: `solve(vc[ovar, ovar])`, and is telling you `vc[ovar, ovar]` doesn't have any dimensions. This is where `ovar` comes from

```
ovar <- which(!(names(coef0(fm1)) %in% names(coef0(fm0))))
```

`fm1`and `fm0` are your two models, which have the same variables.

Comment: Two models on the same object means that "y" should be the same for both models?  I tried it with portfolio-specific variables before, but then i got the error message that the models are not nested. E.g:  
 `lm1<-lm(y~v1_h+v2_h+v3_h+v4_h)  

#Regression 2 

lm2<-lm(y~v1_l+v2_l+v3_l+v4_l)  

#Waldtest  
library(aod)  
library(lmtest)  
Vcov=vcov(lm1,lm2)  

#Attempt 1  
waldtest(lm1,lm2, vcov=Vcov,test="Chisq",name=NULL)`

Comment: The data needs to be the same. Look at the usage in the examples. Competing models (nested, but different).

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to do it with two different datasets, e.g one for each portfolio? Or should the portfolio-specific data be handled in the regression model? So that i would have one regression model which provides different output for each portfolio?