# R: one regression model for 2 different data sets to prepare for waldtest

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have two different data sets. Each of them represents one portfolio of my two portfolios.

y(p) as dependent variable and x1(p), x2(p),x3(p),x4(p) as independent variables. 
(p) indicates a portfolio-specific value. column 1 of each variable represents portfolio 1 and column 2 represents portfolio 2.

The regression equation is:

```
y(p)=∝(p)+ 1(p)*x1(p)+2(p)*x2(p)+3(p)*x3(p)+4(p)*x4(p)
```

What i did so far is to implement a separate regression model for each portfolio in R:

```
lm1 <- lm(y[,1]~x1[,1]+x2[,1]+x3[,1]+x4[,1])
lm2 <- lm(y[,2]~x1[,2]+x2[,2]+x3[,2]+x4[,2])
```

My objective is to compare the two intercepts of both regression models. *Within the scope of this comparison i need to test the joint significance of these intercepts. As far as i can tell,  using the **wald test** should be appropriate.*

If I use the waldtest-function from the lmtest-package it does not work. 
Obviously, because the response variable is not the same for both models.

```
library(lmtest)
waldtest(lm1,lm2)

In waldtest.default(object, ..., test = match.arg(test)) :
  models with response "y[, 2]" removed because response differs from model 1
```

All workarounds I tried so far did not work either, e.g. [R: Waldtest: "Error in solve.default(vc[ovar, ovar]) : 'a' is 0-diml"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230697/r-waldtest-error-in-solve-defaultvcovar-ovar-a-is-0-diml)

My guess is that the regression needs to be done in a different way to fix the problems regarding the **waldtest.**

So that leads to my question:

**Is there a possibility to do the regression in one model, which still generates portfolio-specific intercepts and coefficients?** (I assume, that this would fix the problems with the waldtest-function.)

Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

The following data can be used for a reproducible example:

```
y=matrix(rnorm(10),ncol=2)
x1=matrix(rnorm(10),ncol=2)
x2=matrix(rnorm(10),ncol=2)
x3=matrix(rnorm(10),ncol=2)
x4=matrix(rnorm(10),ncol=2)

lm1 <- lm(y[,1]~x1[,1]+x2[,1]+x3[,1]+x4[,1])
lm2 <- lm(y[,2]~x1[,2]+x2[,2]+x3[,2]+x4[,2])
library(lmtest)
waldtest(lm1,lm2)
```

Best regards, 
Simon

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions

Comment: Thank you! A big step in the right direction for me :)

Comment: @Julius. I know now how to compare coefficients from 2 different regressions. Since the paper I´m trying to rebuild did i the way I described above,  I would be great to learn how to solve this issue doing a wald test. Do you have any information about that?

Comment: I just posted three options to test the equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways to test intercepts equality. The second one is an implementation of the accepted answer to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/93540/10172) question, while the other two are implementations of the second answer to the aforementioned question under different assumptions.

Let

```
n <- 5
y <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 2)
x <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 2)
```

First, we may indeed perform the test with only a single model. For that purpose we create a new vector Y that concatenates `y[, 1]` and `y[, 2]`. As for the independent variables, we create a block-diagonal matrix with the regressors of one model at the upper-left block and those for the other model at the lower-right block. Lastly, I create a group factor indicating the *hidden* model. Hence,

```
library(Matrix)
Y <- c(y)
X <- as.matrix(bdiag(x[, 1], x[, 2]))
G <- factor(rep(0:1, each = n))
```

Now the unrestricted model is

```
m1 <- lm(Y ~ G + X - 1)
```

while the restricted one is

```
m2 <- lm(Y ~ X)
```

Testing for intercepts equality gives

```
library(lmtest)
waldtest(m1, m2)
# Wald test
#
# Model 1: Y ~ G + X - 1
# Model 2: Y ~ X
#   Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
# 1      6                 
# 2      7 -1 0.5473 0.4873
```

so that, as expected, we cannot reject they equality. A problem with this solution, however, is that it is like estimating the two models separately but assuming that the errors have the same variance in both. Also, we don't allow for a cross-correlation between errors.

Second, we can relax the assumption of identical errors variance by estimating two separate models and employing a Z-test as follows.

```
M1 <- lm(y[, 1] ~ x[, 1])
M2 <- lm(y[, 2] ~ x[, 2])

Z <- unname((coef(M1)[1] - coef(M2)[1]) / (coef(summary(M1))[1, 2]^2 + coef(summary(M2))[1, 2])^2)
2 * pnorm(-abs(Z))
# [1] 0.5425736
```

leading to the same conclusion.

Lastly, we can employ the [SUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions) in this way allowing for model-dependent errors variance as well as contemporaneous errors cross-dependence (that may be not necessary in your case, it matters what kind of data you are using). For that we can use the `systemfit` package as follows:

```
library(systemfit)
eq1 <- y[, 1] ~ x[, 1]
eq2 <- y[, 2] ~ x[, 2]
m <- systemfit(list(eq1, eq2), method = "SUR")
```

In this case we also are able to perform the Wald test:

```
R <- matrix(c(1, 0, -1, 0), nrow = 1) # Restriction matrix
linearHypothesis(m, R, test = "Chisq")
# Linear hypothesis test (Chi^2 statistic of a Wald test)
# 
# Hypothesis:
# eq1_((Intercept) - eq2_(Intercept) = 0
#
# Model 1: restricted model
# Model 2: m
#
#   Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
# 1      7                     
# 2      6  1 0.3037     0.5816
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks pretty helpful! I will have a closer look tonight.

Comment: I will probably use the the third approach, since the model dependent errors (residuals?!) are correlated at 0.6.    Do I understand you correctly if I interpret your "errors" as residuals?  Does it make sense to test for multicollinearity using variance inflation factors? In general, it does.   But does it make sense if I use the third approach? If so, is there an efficient way to get the vif ?  (using `vif(m)` doesn´t provide a sufficient output.)

Comment: @dakofla, errors are theoretical, we don't observe them. What we have in the end is residuals; they basically are estimated errors. When certain assumptions hold, we can infer certain things about the errors from the residuals. Looking at the correlation of residuals is a good way to argue for the third approach (you could also test its equality to zero); it's even better if the theory agrees with that. Since you are dealing with portfolios, I think it should make perfect sense. As for collinearity, you may simply do the checks (e.g., vif) with two separate models (as in the 2nd approach).

Comment: Great! I finally feel like I have a "well-enough" understanding of what I´m doing. I really appreciate your effort and your comprehensive replies! Thanks a lot (one more time) :)