# (Wald)Test for comparing two nested feols/plm models

Tags: nested, plm, model-comparison

I want to test if

```
model_1 <- feols(auth ~ dummy_past1 + dummy_past2 + dummy_past3 
| region + date_f, # Fixed Effects
data=df)
```

**is just as good as**

```
model_2 <- feols(auth ~ i(dummy_past1,specific_regions) + i(dummy_past2,specific_regions) + i(dummy_past3, specific_regions) # interaction(dummies * specific regions) 
| region + date_f, # Fixed Effects
data=df)
```

If this was a normal linear regression I would conduct a lrtest (likelihood ratio test). As I heard that a waldtest can also be applied to panel data (?) I conducted a waldtest
**`waldtest(model_1, model_2)`**. Yet, when doing that I get the warning: *"Error in solve.default(vc[ovar, ovar]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.10749e-44"*

Does someone know if doing a waldtest is the **correct approach** here, or if there are any **other tests that I could do on plm or feols regressions?** Or it would also be very helpful if you have ideas on how I could get the waldtest working.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/49231106/4640346 help?

Comment: Yes!! That makes sense :) Thanks a lot!!